# Scaling and panning stage to center

Tags: konvajs

I've used konvajs to create a full screen interactive underground railway map, on each line you can click on a station which pops up a speech bubble with info about the station.

I want to scale up and move the stage so the bubble is positioned in the center of the screen for the life of me I can't figure it out. I already have scaling from center and mouse point scaling.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Hi - a good approach to get a prompt and accurate answer is to show what you already tried and illustrate the issue you are having.  To do that you can post a working snippet of code into your question - clearly you don't want to post your entire project so instead make a cut down representative example of the issue. In your case maybe draw the stage and a couple of shapes then add the code you have so far for the centering and scaling.